# Browser version match - regex breaks in PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using a script to detect the browser and its version that is referenced multiple times on the [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.get-browser.php) page on [php.net](http://php.net).

The file containing the script is saved as UTF-8 and actually it works fine´:

```
// relevant parts only where $ub stores the browser name like "Safari"
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
$pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) . ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $userAgent, $matches);
```

Now we're running a site on a server that uses PHP 5.1.6. Unfortunately it breaks the regex and displays this warning:

> PHP Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 3 in /file.php on line 48

How must the pattern be updated to work properly with PHP 5.1.6?

Comment: You should really upgrade to PHP 5.4

Comment: @crypticツ True. But unfortunately it's not in my hands as somebody else is running a Typo3 on that very same server that can't be updated at the moment - so I'm told.

Comment: WARNING: PHP 5.1 was declared end-of-life in 2006, and has not had any bug fixes or security updates since then. **It is badly out of date and insecure, and should not be in use for a production system**.

Comment: Also, be aware that the HTTP_USER_AGENT string can be unreliable. Some browsers allow it to be spoofed, and also some software such as proxies and anonymisers remove the user agent string entirely. Be careful about relying on it.

Comment: @SDC Thanks for pointing it out again. This question should not lead someone to use PHP 5.1. It's really the dilemma I wrote about in my first comment.

Comment: @SDC That's true. It's used only to display a few hints (iOS, IE7 etc.). So there's nothing important that depends on it.

Comment: @insertusernamehere - re php5.1: fair enough. In fact, if anything this question should lead others *away* from php5.1! :-) However, you mentioned it's because of Typo3. I'll note that: (a) current versions of Typo3 support current PHP versions, so it's clearly an out-of-date and probably insecure version of Typo3 as well, and (b) it is possible to run multiple versions of PHP on the same server; there's no reason why one out-of-date head-in-the-sand user should hold others back from being secure.

Comment: @SDC All true. In this case it's really this: I update my part in the SVN and somebody else's task is it to upload it and to run the server. We had a similar discussion right after he told me that it's PHP 5.1.6. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere - fair enough. I'll leave it at that. As long as everyone is aware of the potential problems, and if (when) the server gets hacked, no-one can say they didn't know.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you are trying to use isn't introduced until PHP 5.2.2. `(?<name>pattern)`. You should be able to use this instead `(?P<name>pattern)`.